# Suggestions on how to store age and other time derived data in MongoDB using Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to store my users `age` on `MongoDB` and i want to calculate the `age` of the user dynamically and update it autonomously when possible.

I'm thinking of two approaches one is to store the date and on query use today's date as a reference and find the difference but the problem with this is the `age` will not be updated on the schema in `MongoDB`, how do i solve this?

The other is to set a hook for an `API` and trigger that `API` to update the details.

My schema looks something like this, though i am computing the age when saving it won't get updated as and when needed. Also as told taking today's date as a reference is affecting our analytics.

```
dateOfBirth: Date,
age: Number
```

Comment: Preferred solution is to just save the `dateOfBirth` and calculate the age at run time if this create problem in analytics. Then schedule a cron job for midnight every day that will update the `age`.

Answer (score 1):

You can store as DOB and project age while querying using aggregation framework

```
db.getCollection('callmodels').aggregate([{
    $project: {
        name : 1,
        email: 1,
        age: {$trunc:{$divide: [ {$subtract: [new Date(), '$dob']},1000 * 60 * 60 * 24* 365]}}}
    }
])
```